# Default target for capistrano

Tags: capistrano

It's possible to set a custom target for capistrano, so instead of

```
cap production deploy
```

or

```
cap production my_custom:task
```

I can use

```
cap deploy
cap my_custom:task
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easy way you can create alias for command **cap production**

```
alias capp="cap production"
```

and after that you can use command how

```
capp deploy
capp my_custom:task
```

for run alias for your session you can set that into **~/.bashrc**